# How to move 2 cube at the same time? New to Blender

Tags: python, animation

I wanted to make an animation. I added two box and I made one of the box rotates about a circle. For some reason, the other box follows the 3-axis intersected at the other box,instead of staying at the origin. What did I do wrong? Thank you.

```
import bpy
import math


if not 'Cube' in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()

if not 'Cube2' in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()

fpr = 120.0
step_size = 2*math.pi / fpr

radius=5

def set_object_location(n):
    x = math.sin(n) * radius
    y = math.cos(n) * radius
    z = 0.0
    ob = bpy.data.objects.get("Cube")
    ob.location = (x, y, z)
    obs = bpy.data.objects.get("Cube.001")
    obs.location = (0, 0, 0)


def update(scene):
    frame = scene.frame_current
    angle = frame % fpr

    if angle == 0:
        set_object_location(angle)
    else:
        set_object_location(angle*step_size)


bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(update)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you assign a fixed position to the 2nd cube:

```
 obs = bpy.data.objects.get("Cube.001")
 obs.location = (0, 0, 0)
```

To be able to move them independendly you could add all objects to a list and move them while iterating:

```
if not 'Cube' in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()

if not 'Cube.001' in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()

ob = bpy.data.objects.get("Cube")
ob2 = bpy.data.objects.get("Cube.001")
obs = [ob,ob2]

fpr = 120.0
step_size = 2*math.pi / fpr

radius=5

def set_object_location(ob,n):
    x = math.sin(n) * radius
    y = math.cos(n) * radius
    z = 0.0
    ob.location = (x, y, z)


def update(scene):
    frame = scene.frame_current
    angle = frame % fpr

    count=0.0
    for ob in obs:
        if angle == 0:
            set_object_location(ob,angle+count)
        else:
            set_object_location(ob,angle*(step_size+count))
        count = count + step_size


bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(update)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work for me - one cube rotates around the other (which remains stationary at the origin). The only issue I can see with the code is that the initialisation to add the cubes refers to 'Cube' and 'Cube2' but the later logic refers to 'Cube' and 'Cube.001'.

I suspect the most likely cause of your issues is that you have run the script multiple time and, perhaps, an earlier copy of your code is still registered in the handler. Try saving your work (after changing 'Cube2' to match 'Cube.001'), closing Blender, and re-opening and running - and see if that resolves your problem.